# Laravel 5.7 session expires immediately after log in

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.7

I have an issue in Laravel 5.7 where after logging in on a production server, the session immediately returns the dreadful 419 session expiration page.

Sometimes you can click on 'Go Home' and it redirects you to the homepage (logged in) whereas sometimes you have to try to sign in again.

The authentication system is from `php artisan make:auth`, nothing special. Has anyone experienced any issues with it?

I am completely baffled as my staging site is hosted on the same server with same configurations, but this is only an issue on production.

The sessions use the file driver, and yes the directory is writeable.

Just curious if anyone has come across this before.

Here is my production `.env`, again nothing out of the ordinary, just a basic out of the box setup.

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=production
APP_KEY=base64:e4HlhHYT8tg68K3vpM3qe2d/ARdkxr1rngDScMRpEQk=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=https://production.example.com/

LOG_CHANNEL=stack

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=db.example.com
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=db
DB_USERNAME=user
DB_PASSWORD=password

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_CONNECTION=database
QUEUE_DRIVER=database

SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io

MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"
```

My login form is the following (basic laravel auth setup)

```
 <form method="POST" action="{{ route('login') }}">
                        @csrf

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="email" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('E-Mail Address') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autofocus>

                                @if ($errors->has('email'))
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="password" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Password') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="password" required>

                                @if ($errors->has('password'))
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                                <div class="form-check">
                                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="remember" id="remember" {{ old('remember') ? 'checked' : '' }}>

                                    <label class="form-check-label" for="remember">
                                        {{ __('Remember Me') }}
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                            <div class="col-md-8 offset-md-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    {{ __('Login') }}
                                </button>

                                @if (Route::has('password.request'))
                                    <a class="btn btn-link" href="{{ route('password.request') }}">
                                        {{ __('Forgot Your Password?') }}
                                    </a>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

I added a snippet for a logout function in my `homecontroller.php`

```
public function doLogout()
    {
        Auth::logout(); // log the user out of our application
        Session::flush();
        return Redirect::to('login'); // redirect the user to the login screen
    }
```

I referenced it in my routes

```
Route::get('logout', array('uses' => 'HomeController@doLogout'));
```

And my logout form looks like the following, prebuilt from `php artisan make:auth`

```
<a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('logout') }}" onclick="event.preventDefault(); document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">{{ __('Logout') }}</a>
<form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
@csrf
</form>
```

EDIT: Here is my `session.php` configuration

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Str;

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Session Driver
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option controls the default session "driver" that will be used on
    | requests. By default, we will use the lightweight native driver but
    | you may specify any of the other wonderful drivers provided here.
    |
    | Supported: "file", "cookie", "database", "apc",
    |            "memcached", "redis", "array"
    |
    */

    'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'file'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Lifetime
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify the number of minutes that you wish the session
    | to be allowed to remain idle before it expires. If you want them
    | to immediately expire on the browser closing, set that option.
    |
    */

    'lifetime' => env('SESSION_LIFETIME', 120),

    'expire_on_close' => false,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Encryption
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option allows you to easily specify that all of your session data
    | should be encrypted before it is stored. All encryption will be run
    | automatically by Laravel and you can use the Session like normal.
    |
    */

    'encrypt' => false,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session File Location
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When using the native session driver, we need a location where session
    | files may be stored. A default has been set for you but a different
    | location may be specified. This is only needed for file sessions.
    |
    */

    'files' => storage_path('framework/sessions'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Database Connection
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When using the "database" or "redis" session drivers, you may specify a
    | connection that should be used to manage these sessions. This should
    | correspond to a connection in your database configuration options.
    |
    */

    'connection' => env('SESSION_CONNECTION', null),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Database Table
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When using the "database" session driver, you may specify the table we
    | should use to manage the sessions. Of course, a sensible default is
    | provided for you; however, you are free to change this as needed.
    |
    */

    'table' => 'sessions',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Cache Store
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When using the "apc" or "memcached" session drivers, you may specify a
    | cache store that should be used for these sessions. This value must
    | correspond with one of the application's configured cache stores.
    |
    */

    'store' => env('SESSION_STORE', null),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Sweeping Lottery
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Some session drivers must manually sweep their storage location to get
    | rid of old sessions from storage. Here are the chances that it will
    | happen on a given request. By default, the odds are 2 out of 100.
    |
    */

    'lottery' => [2, 100],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Cookie Name
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may change the name of the cookie used to identify a session
    | instance by ID. The name specified here will get used every time a
    | new session cookie is created by the framework for every driver.
    |
    */

    'cookie' => env(
        'SESSION_COOKIE',
        Str::slug(env('APP_NAME', 'laravel'), '_').'_session'
    ),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Cookie Path
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | The session cookie path determines the path for which the cookie will
    | be regarded as available. Typically, this will be the root path of
    | your application but you are free to change this when necessary.
    |
    */

    'path' => '/',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Cookie Domain
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may change the domain of the cookie used to identify a session
    | in your application. This will determine which domains the cookie is
    | available to in your application. A sensible default has been set.
    |
    */

    'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN', null),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | HTTPS Only Cookies
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | By setting this option to true, session cookies will only be sent back
    | to the server if the browser has a HTTPS connection. This will keep
    | the cookie from being sent to you if it can not be done securely.
    |
    */

    'secure' => env('SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE', false),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | HTTP Access Only
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Setting this value to true will prevent JavaScript from accessing the
    | value of the cookie and the cookie will only be accessible through
    | the HTTP protocol. You are free to modify this option if needed.
    |
    */

    'http_only' => true,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Same-Site Cookies
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option determines how your cookies behave when cross-site requests
    | take place, and can be used to mitigate CSRF attacks. By default, we
    | do not enable this as other CSRF protection services are in place.
    |
    | Supported: "lax", "strict"
    |
    */

    'same_site' => null,

];
```

Thanks!

Comment: can you share your session.php configuration ?

Comment: Look at the Network traffic in your browser's Dev Tools, are the cookies being set correctly?

Comment: the problem is probably with the session driver. sometimes using file as session driver causes these problems. try to switch to a db or redis driver.

Comment: check this [issue](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/9787) on github

Comment: added the session config file above @DjellalMohamedAniss

Comment: why `logout` needs to have a post request in a form? Your route suggests that it is a GET request.

Comment: well, I don't know this is relevant to you, but I'll explain something I experienced recently. Similar to your case I had two sites on the same server with the same domain but different ports. When I open both sites using the same browser session ids on cookies get mixed up so it always gave me 419 status. because browsers only use host/domain to differentiate the cookies. So if you are using the same domain. you should check this one

Comment: as @Yasin Patel said, i think you should change your session driver to DB, it's faster and more secure. problems like yours happens a lot on AWS when i searched on the net.

Comment: why would you share the logout code if your problem is with login?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have faced the same problem on AWS EBS.

Here are two solution :

1. Give `775` permission to `storage` directory. Maybe a server not have permission to create a session file.
2. Change session driver from file to database.

   `SESSION_DRIVER=database`
   So session will manage by database.

for this you also need to perform below command

```
php artisan session:table

composer dump-autoload

php artisan migrate
```

For reference : https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/session

Comment: Thanks! My server is indeed on AWS, ill try switching the driver to db and get back to you!